# How to show a radio button one by one on php or html

Tags: php, html

I'm new to php and html and I was wondering, how having a code like below:

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form>
  <p>Question Number 1</p>
  <input type="radio" name="question1" value="A">A<br>
  <input type="radio" name="question1" value="B">B<br>
  <input type="radio" name="question1" value="C">C<br> 
  <input type="radio" name="question1" value="D">D
  <p>Question Number 2</p>
  <input type="radio" name="question2" value="A">A<br>
  <input type="radio" name="question2" value="B">B<br>
  <input type="radio" name="question2" value="C">C<br> 
  <input type="radio" name="question2" value="D">D
  <p>Question Number 3</p>
  <input type="radio" name="question3" value="A">A<br>
  <input type="radio" name="question3" value="B">B<br>
  <input type="radio" name="question3" value="C">C<br> 
  <input type="radio" name="question3" value="D">D
  <p>Question Number 4</p>
  <input type="radio" name="question4" value="A">A<br>
  <input type="radio" name="question4" value="B">B<br>
  <input type="radio" name="question4" value="C">C<br> 
  <input type="radio" name="question4" value="D">D
</form> 

</body>
</html>
```

> I want to show a question one bye one with button next and with check if
>   a value is null. What should I use? PHP or Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('input[type="radio"]').on('change', function(e) {
  $('#'+e.target.name+'').hide();
  var nextRadioGroupName = "question" + (parseInt(e.target.name.replace('question', '')) + 1);
  $('#'+nextRadioGroupName+'').show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <form>
   <div id = "question1">
      <p>Question Number 1</p>
      <input type="radio" name="question1" value="A">A<br>
      <input type="radio" name="question1" value="B">B<br>
      <input type="radio" name="question1" value="C">C<br> 
      <input type="radio" name="question1" value="D">D
   </div>
   <div id = "question2" style="display:none">
      <p>Question Number 2</p>
      <input type="radio" name="question2" value="A">A<br>
      <input type="radio" name="question2" value="B">B<br>
      <input type="radio" name="question2" value="C">C<br> 
      <input type="radio" name="question2" value="D">D
   </div>
   <div id = "question3" style="display:none">
      <p>Question Number 3</p>
      <input type="radio" name="question3" value="A">A<br>
      <input type="radio" name="question3" value="B">B<br>
      <input type="radio" name="question3" value="C">C<br> 
      <input type="radio" name="question3" value="D">D
   </div>
   <div id = "question4" style="display:none">
      <p>Question Number 4</p>
      <input type="radio" name="question4" value="A">A<br>
      <input type="radio" name="question4" value="B">B<br>
      <input type="radio" name="question4" value="C">C<br> 
      <input type="radio" name="question4" value="D">D
   </div>
    </form>
```

- Firstly add a div element for per question group to easily show/hide them
- Define change event with `Jquery` and find the next question group as iteration like "question1", "question2" etc.
- Then show the next question group

Comment: this code is amazing, but how we hide the previous question?

Comment: i got one last question, if we want to post it and send it to the another action on form? if in the normal code we're using botton and type=submit, how to using this on your code?

Comment: Specify the form action endpoint (something like savequestions.php) and get the posted input values from that php file like "$_POST['question1'], $_POST['question2']" etc.;

Comment: yeah, i try it but when i tryto put action on form like action="savequestions.php" but when the last question i clicked, it does't go to savequestions.php? or it must be add something on js?

Comment: Do you want to pass input values when last question is marked or do you want to use submit button ?

Comment: It's a valid code, but I believe, that it has a lot of drawbacks, like loading jQuery(for the purpose of just creating such a simple thing it's kind of pointless), also it doesn't allow user to change their answer once they clicked the radio box. In my opinion it'd be better to add a button like 'next' and then assign action responsible for changing the displayed question

Comment: @Rainman i just want to pass input values when last question is marked

Comment: Just determine the last question is marked and submit the form using jquery. I believe you can handle it.

Comment: Sorry man, this site doesn't have a write my full code style. Show your effort !